# Using nth-child css for entries from database

Tags: html, css

I have a table that displays multiple rows from database. 
I want to change background color for each second row.

I tried to use nth-child in css but it's not working. It displays all rows with the same background color. 
I think is because i have just one row in html table, but i have a while statement who gives me multiple rows.

Thx for help.
My code :
[image]

**CSS**

```
.responstable {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #024457;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #167F92;
}
.responstable tr {
  border: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
}
.responstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EAF3F3;
}
.responstable th {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: #167F92;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
}
td:empty {     background: rgb(247, 236, 236);
}
.responstable td {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media {
  .responstable td {
    border: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
  }
}
.responstable td {
  text-align: left;
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media {
  .responstable th, 
  .responstable td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}
```

**PHP / HTML**

```
<?php 
       include('connect-db.php');
       $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
       $result =mysql_query($sql);
       {
        ?>
<table border="1px" align="center" class="responstable" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th span style="font-weight: normal;">Contrat</th>
            <th span style="font-weight: normal;">Client</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
       }
      while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data['contract'] ?></td>
            <td style=" text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $data['client'] ?></td>
        </tr> <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify second row or column? Code works fine for rows: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/das09xnf/

Comment: I want to change row background color for each second row displayed from database. I don't need to modify nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You output a `tbody` for each row of the database. So every `tr` is the only `tr` in its `tbody`. That won't work.

Solution: output the `<tbody>` start tag before starting the `while` loop that outputs the rows.
I think that's what you meant to write all along, since I see you also output only one `</tbody>` end tag, after the loop ends.

Side note: while I wrote "that won't work", I mean it confuses the CSS, not that the table would have problems handling multiple tbodies. (In fact, you could have made this work by leaving the PHP as is and changing the CSS to `tbody:nth-child(odd) tr`. Just saying.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. i crashed the head modifying the css and searching another way. But it was so simple.